# Convert varargin and varargout to cell arrays

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to call a function with the following signature

```
function [z varargout] = intersectm(varargin)
```

where `varargin` is a comma separated list of matrices and `varargout` is also a comma separated list of matrices. This function was intended to be used as the following.

`[D, ia, ib, ic] = intersectm(A, B, C, 'rows')`

where `D` contains the rows that are common in matrices A, B, and C, and `ia`, `ib`,  and `ic` contain which indices of A, B, and C contain the common elements.

In my program, I generate `n` matrices that must get passed into `intersectm`, and I expect `n+1` outputs from this function.

How do I pass in a cell array of `n` matrices into `varargin` and convert the `varargout` into a cell array of `n+1` matrices?

I tried using `my_matrices{:}` as the `varargin` but the shapes of the matrices are not preserved. They are just turned into a column vector.

This is the [function](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28341-set-functions-with-multiple-inputs) in question.

**EDIT:**

Current:

```
D, ia, ib, ic = intersectm(A, B, C)
```

Expected:

```
outputs = intersectm({A, B, C})
```

where

`outputs{1}` is `D`

`outputs{2}` is `ia`

`outputs{3}` is `ib`

`outputs{4}` is `ic`

Comment: It would help to see actual inputs and corresponding outputs

Comment: @Wolfie do you mean my expected input and output or what the function actually does? You may find the latter here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28341-set-functions-with-multiple-inputs

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: @SardarUsama sure but of what exactly? Do you want an example of calling the existing function or what I want the function to return?

Comment: Both. This is what makes an example complete and verifiable

Comment: You've tried to *describe* what functionality you want, essentially it's much more powerful to *show* us what functionality you want. What the `intersectm` function actually does seems irrelevant to this question, but it's unclear what your actual expected input/output behaviour is

Comment: @Wolfie thanks for providing feedback instead of downvoting. I thought it made it clear that I require the same output as intersectm but in the form of a cell array instead of a varargout.

Comment: There are two highlighted words (in italic) in Wolfie's last comment. I hope you have also noticed that already :)

Comment: @Wolfie I have updated the original post.

Comment: @SardarUsama I have updated the original post.

Comment: So does `D = {A B C}; E = cell(4,1)` then `[E{:}] = intersectm(D{:})` answer your calling?

Comment: @Wolfie as noted in the OP, using D{:} as an input doesn’t preserve the structure of A, B, and C. They all get flattened into a column vector

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. Please provide an example *with actual matrices* where they get flattened into a column vector and show those flattened results.

Comment: This is exactly why I asked for example inputs, and Sardar asked for a full [mcve], because `D{:}` should just pass the contents of the cell array `D` in as separate arguments, without changing anything about them. Now you've accepted the answer which copied my comment and you say doesn't work? So was your original issue not an issue?

Comment: I think it worked. If you want I can reward you the answer @Wolfie

Comment: sure you can delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
in = {A B C}; % input
out = cell(1, numel(in)+1); % cell for output
[out{:}] = intersectm(in{:});
```

Comment: Nice work [comment copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51425972/convert-varargin-and-varargout-to-cell-arrays?noredirect=1#comment89824100_51425972). You didn't even capture all the syntax, this won't work as expected

Comment: Not quite. Passing a cell array into varargin doesn’t work

Comment: Ah, the same as your comment :)

Comment: @Wolfie yes, missing {:}